# Controller does not accept data POST 404

Tags: java, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

Help me please, I'm writing a site on java ee with spring mvc, I need to send the request to the servlet, but I get error 404.

**my html:**

```
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="sendRequest()">
```

**my js:**

```
function sendRequest(){
var str = "this is string";
    $.ajax({
            url:"ajaxtest",
            type:"POST",
            //data:JSON.stringify(myJson).toString(),
            data:str,
            success: alert("good")
        });}
```

**my controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="ajaxtest", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getAjax(String myStr){
        System.out.print("result : "+myStr);
    }
```

**result console browser:**

```
POST http://localhost/MyProject/ajaxtest 404 (Not Found)
m.ajaxTransport.send - jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4 
m.extend.ajax - jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4
sendRequest - add.jsp:139
onclick - add.jsp:213
```

**result console ide:**

```
INFO: Server startup in 2991 ms
result : null
```

Please help me!

Comment: What is your context path? Also, is your controller also mapped to some url?

Comment: I start my relative paths with a /  url:"/ajaxtest" ?   Throw in a cache:false to for kicks.

Comment: controller is not mapped
I do not use RequestMapping a controller
`http://localhost/MyProject/add.jsp`

Comment: Whats your servlet xml look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of items you need to do to make it work. My answer is based on the information that is in post.

You ajax data has to be a key value pair like below to send a simple string.

```
function sendRequest(){
var str = "this is string";
    $.ajax({
            url:"ajaxtest",
            type:"POST",
            //data:JSON.stringify(myJson).toString(),
            data:{myStr:str},
            success: alert("good")
        });}
```

You have to tell spring how to resolve myStr on controller method, else Spring will not be able to know how to resolve it. In our case we will use @RequestParam annotation, which tells spring to get it from request parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value="ajaxtest", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getAjax(@RequestParam String myStr){
        System.out.print("result : "+myStr);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, now works, but I still get the error

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, change:

```
public void getAjax(String myStr) {
```

to:

```
public void getAjax(@RequestBody String myStr) {
```

`@RequestBody` tells Spring to use the contents of the request as the parameter of your controller method.